# String.format ignores everything but first argument

Tags: java, string, format, language-lawyer

Java's `String` type has a `format` method, but calling it ignores everything inside the template and only returns the first argument.

```
String s = "name: %s, age: %d".format("bob", 42);
assertEquals("name: bob, age: 42", s); // fails, s.equals("bob")
```

Even with an empty template, the first argument is returned:

```
s = "".format("alice", 21); // returns "alice"
```

Java 8 and Java 11 both exhibit the same problematic behavior.

The same code works in Python:

```py
s = 'name: {}, age: {}'.format('bob', 42)
s == 'name: bob, age: 42' # True
```

Why is that? There's no compilation error and the program runs without exception. It is very not obvious why it behaves this way. How to properly use the `format` method of a string?

I read somewhere that in object-oriented languages, the object is the first argument of a method. Does that play a role here?

Comment: [`String::format`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) is a static method, expecting the format template as 1st argument and the parameters as varargs (`Stirng.format("name: %s, age: %d", "bob", 42)`). Did you mean instance-method [`String::formatted`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)) (`"name: %s, age: %d".formatted("bob", 42)`)?

Comment: String.format("name: %s, age: %d","bob", 42), format on string workis with {}

Comment: Turn on all compiler warnings, and pay attention to them.  The compiler will point out the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method [`String.format(String format, Object... args)` (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) is a static method; we use it like this:

```
String s1 = String.format("name: %s, age: %d", "bob", 42);
```

Alternatively we can use the instance-method [`String.formatted(Object... args)`, which was introduced with Java 15 (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)):

```
String s2 = "name: %s, age: %d".formatted("bob", 42);
```

[<kbd>`JDoodle` demo</kbd>](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/OVz)

Comment: But why is there no compilation error if it is used incorrectly? Why does it still "work", but produce wrong results? What happens to the original string, why is it ignored?

Comment: @knittl Callling a static mehtod through an instance is allowed in java (although not recommended). Thus, calling `"foo".format("bar")` is equivalent to calling  `String.format("bar")`, which just returns `"bar"` since there is nothing to format.

Comment: Then why was the question closed? This is the perfect answer to the question (with a solution for Java 15+). The question even gathered two answers, which means it was definitely answerable.

Comment: Don't ask me. I did not close-vote. I did, however, vote to re-open.

Comment: @knittl There is no compilation error, but there is a compilation warning.  Unlike in C, Java compiler warnings usually indicate that something is syntactically permitted but is likely logically incorrect.  Warnings are not printed by default, alas.  Personally I always compile with `-Xlint -Werror`.

Answer (score 0):

`String.format` is a static Method, you should call it this way.

```
String s = String.format("name: %s, age: %d", "bob", 42);
```

First param is the original string, then you can add multiple parameters as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The *[String#format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))* method is useful for multi-line *String* literals.

```java
String.format("name: %s, " +
              "age: %d", "bob", 42);
```

And, the *[String#formatted](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...))* method is just convenient, considering you don't specify *String*.
It was added in *Java 15*.

```java
"name: %s, age: %d".formatted("bob", 42)
```

Comment: Your example is not a multi-line string literal. It’s also not clear why the static method should be more useful for multi-line literals than for ordinary string literals.